# With pytest under Windows, create an unreadable file for unit testing

Tags: python, windows, unit-testing, pytest

I'm using `pytest` under Windows and one of the thing I have to test is behaviour when a file cannot be read and the operation raises `PermissionError`.

In my unit test I cannot use `chmod()` because under Windows it cannot be used to remove read permission.

I understand that I can achieve what I want using the `tmp_path` fixture for creating a temporary file and then use the `icacls` command (with the help of `subprocess.run()` in the test unit) to properly remove read permission, but I wonder if I'm missing a much simpler way of writing such an unit test.

I can test the relevant code in other ways, but I would like to know a way of creating unreadable files for testing under `pytest`, just in case I need that in the future, and for learning purposes (as I'm quite new to `pytest`.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't think you need to be testing with a real file. After all, your goal is not to test Python's/OS's functionality. Your goal is to test how **your** code behaves when a particular exception is raised. Therefore, **mock it**. Patch the relevant bits and make them raise the exception you want.

Comment: You are right, and I have thought of that, but I have to test permission restoring and retrying the read, etc. (and MORE code may appear in the future, I'm not writing it, I'm just creating the test suite) so it is actually simpler for now to use a real file. And anyway I was just curious if there was an alternative to running `icacls`, which is what I have ended using. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Of course, in hindsight, I should have asked for something more generic, like how to create such file on Python running on Windows, but I was wondering about some `pytest` plugin I'm not aware of, or some obvious solution I was missing.